# Indicating checkbox values from MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 MySQL tables:

> **properties (these are properties)**
>   id | address | price
>   1 | 123 St. | 100,000
>   2 | 456 St. | 200,000
>   **categories (these are categories of amenities for properties)**
>   id | title
>   1 | Kitchen
>   2 | Entertainment
>   
>   **items (these are items under the categories above)**
>   id | catid | item
>   1 | 1 | Stove
>   2 | 1 | Fridge
>   3 | 2 | TV
>   4 | 2 | Couch
>   **propertyamenities (these are the particular amenities for a property)**
>   id | listingid | amenityid
>   1 | 1 | 3
>   2 | 1 | 4

I have built a form where the user can select the various amenities for a given property using checkboxes, which inserts from PHP into MySQL tables above.

I now need to allow the user to edit the amenities (using checkboxes) for a given property. The code I am currently using is:

```
              $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT a.title AS maincategory, b.item AS smallcategory, b.id as itemid FROM categories a, items b WHERE a.id = b.catid ORDER BY maincategory ASC, smallcategory ASC") or die(mysqli_error($con));

              // keep track of previous maincategory
              $previous_maincategory = NULL;

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {

                // if maincategory has changed from previouscategory then display it
                if ($previous_maincategory != $row['maincategory']) {
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top"><strong>';
                        echo $row['maincategory'];
                        echo '</strong></td>
                        </tr>';
                }

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";


                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='amenities[]' value='".$row['itemid']."'>".$row['smallcategory'];

                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                // record what the previous category was
                $previous_maincategory = $row['maincategory'];
              }
```

This displays the categories and the items as checkboxes. I'm not sure how for a given property, to modify this script and have the associated checkboxes "checked". I presume I need to add in the propertyamenities table to the query, and a WHERE clause to indicate which property (e.g.,1) is being edited, but not sure how to add in the third table.

**EDIT**
I am closer, but it is returning the same item twice.

```
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT a.title AS maincategory, b.item AS smallcategory, b.id as itemid, c.amenityid as amenity FROM categories a, items b, propertyamenities c WHERE a.id = b.catid and c.listingid = '$id' ORDER BY maincategory ASC, smallcategory ASC") or die(mysqli_error($con));


              // keep track of previous maincategory
              $previous_maincategory = NULL;
              $myprevious_maincategory = NULL;  
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {

                // if maincategory has changed from previouscategory then display it
                if ($previous_maincategory != $row['maincategory']) {
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top"><strong>';
                        echo $row['maincategory'];
                        echo '</strong></td>
                        </tr>';
                }


                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";

                if ($row['amenity'] == $row['itemid'])
                {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='amenities[]' value='".$row['itemid']."' checked>".$row['smallcategory'];
                }
                else
                  {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='amenities[]' value='".$row['itemid']."'>".$row['smallcategory'];
                  }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                // record what the previous category was
                $previous_maincategory = $row['maincategory'];
              }

      ?>
```

**EDIT**
Screenshot of current state:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
/* Arrays will be used to store the property address and amenity ids */
/* in order to check against undesired duplicate echoing. */
$arr_address = [];
$arr_amenity_ids = []; 

/* The four tables are joined here to get the required fields. */
/* Here, let $pid be the id of the property being considered: */
$s = "SELECT a.address as Address, b.title as Amenity, c.item as Item, b.id, c.id FROM properties a JOIN categories b JOIN items c JOIN propertyamenities d ON b.id = c.catid AND a.id = d.listingid AND c.id = d.amenityid AND a.id = '$pid';";
$q = mysqli_query($con,$s);

while(list($address, $amenity, $item, $amenity_id, $item_id) = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){

/* Can have a heading for the property address */
   if(!in_array($address, $arr_address)){ 
        echo '<h2>Property Address: '.$address.'</h2>'; $arr_address[] = $address;
    }

/* A heading for each amenity once: */
   if(!in_array($amenity_id,$arr_amenity_ids)){
       echo '<strong>'.$amenity.'</strong>'; $arr_amenity_ids[] = $amenity_id;
    }
    echo '<br/><input type="checkbox" value="'.$item_id.'"/> '.$item;
 }
```

Comment: This is good, but not quite what I am after. I worked at it a bit and am closer, except it is returning the items twice.

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify the questions a bit further and include a screenshot of sample output or desired form, perhaps with a sample third row in the `propertyamenities` table as `3 | 2 | 4 |` ?

Comment: Yes, please see above screenshot. As you can see, the selected values are returning, however, each item is being listed twice.

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot. It helped me understand better. I have changed my answer accordingly using the same principles as in the previous answer.